# Show products from server with diffrent sorts

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, rx-java2

I'm working on an ecommerce Android application using MVVM & RXJAVA & KOIN with kotlin and the product request URL has query type parameters which will show latest products, most popular product, most expensive to cheap and most cheap to expensive and I want to show sort in main page with RecyclerView but all of my RecyclerViews showing the same thing. How do I fix this?

```
interface ApiService{ 

    @GET("product/list")
    fun getLatestProducts(@Query("sort")sort:String):Single<List<Product>>
}

    class MainViewModel(productRepository: ProductRepository,bannerRepository: BannerRepository):NikeViewModel() {
    val productLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Product>>()
    val productLiveData1 = MutableLiveData<List<Product>>()
    val progressBarLiveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val bannerLiveData=MutableLiveData<List<Banner>>()
    init {
        progressBarLiveData.value = true
        productRepository.getLatestProducts(SORT_LATEST)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doFinally { progressBarLiveData.value = false }
            .subscribe(object : SingleObserver<List<Product>> {
                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                    compositeDisposable.add(d)
                }

                override fun onSuccess(t: List<Product>) {
                    productLiveData.value = t
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

            })


        productRepository.getLatestProducts(SORT_POPULAR)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doFinally { progressBarLiveData.value = false }
            .subscribe(object : SingleObserver<List<Product>> {
                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                    compositeDisposable.add(d)
                }

                override fun onSuccess(t: List<Product>) {
                    productLiveData1.value = t
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

            })

class MainFragment:NikeFragment(),ProductListAdapter.ProductOnClickedListener {

    val mainViewModel:MainViewModel by viewModel()
    val productListAdapter:ProductListAdapter by inject()
    val productListAdapter2:ProductListAdapter by inject()
    private val TAG = "MainFragment"
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment,container,false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        latest_product_rv.layoutManager=
           LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(),RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false)

        productListAdapter.productOnClickedListener=this

        popular_product_rv.layoutManager=
            LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(),RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false)
        popular_product_rv.adapter=productListAdapter
        val bannerSlider=view.findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.bannerSliderMain)
        mainViewModel.productLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            latest_product_rv.adapter=productListAdapter
            productListAdapter.products=it as ArrayList<Product>

        }

        mainViewModel.productLiveData1.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            popular_product_rv.adapter=productListAdapter
            productListAdapter2.products=it as ArrayList<Product>

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the same adapter on both.

This

```
        mainViewModel.productLiveData1.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            popular_product_rv.adapter=productListAdapter
            productListAdapter2.products=it as ArrayList<Product>

        }
```

should be

```
        mainViewModel.productLiveData1.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            popular_product_rv.adapter=productListAdapter2
            productListAdapter2.products=it as ArrayList<Product>

        }
```